# Regex starts with 'https', 'http', or '/' for a property in MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

```
[Display(Name = "Url")]
[RegularExpression("/^(\/|https?:\/\/)/i", ErrorMessage = "Url must start with 'http://', 'https://', or '/'")]
public string Url{ get; set; }
```

I'm trying to use Regex for data annotations on one of my properties in my model. It must start with http, https, or a forward slash. I'm trying to escape  the forward slash in Regex but keep getting an error on "Unrecognized escape sequence." Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use a string literal and drop the delimiters to get `@"^(/|https?://)"`. See [docs for RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.8). Otherwise you'll probably have to escape twice, i.e. `\\\`.

Comment: Try it like this: `@"(?i)^(/|https?://)"` if you want to make the pattern also case-insensitive.